# Using a DIR command to display subdir's with files...suppress subdir's with no files

Tags: windows, command-line

I am currently running the command `dir /b/s *.*` on a specific directory that has subdirectories.  How do I only get a list of directories that does not show empty directories, but only directories that have files.

Comment: You say "get a list of directories" but I think you're really asking for the files, right?  Do you want to see the directory names, or just fully-qualified filenames with paths, only for files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following structure (and this would be the result of dir /s /b)

```
test\1
test\2
test\3
test\1\fred.txt
test\2\wilma.txt
```

For a list of directories containing at least one file:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b /s /ad') do @for /f %j in ('dir %i ^| find "File(s)"') do @if not %j==0 echo %i
```

Results:

```
test\1
test\2
```

For a list of files but not including lines that are just the directories:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b /s /ad') do @for /f %j in ('dir %i ^| find "File(s)"') do @if not %j==0 dir /b /s %i
```

Results:

```
test\1\fred.txt
test\2\wilma.txt
```

Remember that if this is done inside of a batch file you have to double up the % signs, e.g. %%i and %%j

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of folders without files:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad') do dir "%%a" /b /a-d >nul 2>&1 && echo %%a)>"folderlist.txt"
```